# How can I highlight paragraphs in emails and add private notes to them?

Tags: software-recommendation, email, annotation

I would like to highlight parts of emails, without having to print them out and use a highlighter pen. I also want to add notes. I ideally want to see the highlights appear when I view an email a second time, so simply forwarding the email to myself and adding let's say a line of stars is not ideal - I'm looking for something more convenient. I know how to do this with PDFs and web pages, but what about emails?

I am willing to consider using whichever software or email client will let me do this on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click on an E-Mail to **create a memo from it in Evolution**. It's not exactly what you want but except for Ooutlook I don't know any mail-client that supports comments on mails.

You could also check out these **addons for Thunderbird**:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/xnote/
- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/message-notes/

According to [an e-mail](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/evolution-list/2007-February/msg00149.html) **tomboy** can also link notes and task to e-mails you received (see [Addins](http://projects.gnome.org/tomboy/plugins.html)->Evolution).

**All solutions lack the highlighting you need.**

Since both comments and highlighting in e-Mails would be reasonable and useful feature, you could suggest its integration into evolution.