# What E-mail clients are available?

Tags: software-recommendation, email

What the best E-mail clients are available and integrate well with Ubuntu.

**Including the features:**

- Support of notifcations for messages/News(RSS).
- Integrate well with the events in the time/date indicator
- What E-mail services do they support ?
- etc.

**Edit**: Despite the features included above , I want a list of all the E-mail Clients available to use , and if possible to make it a community-wiki post for each answer one email client.

Comment: Do webmail clients count? Or are you looking for offline clients?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Sorry I read your comment wrong at first, I mean I want E-mail Clients Like evolution and thunderbird below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I enjoy [Evolution](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/) the default mail client for Ubuntu.

- An integrated e-mail program with an address book, calendars and tasks.
- IMAP, POP3, and SMTP support
- Intelligent Junk Mail control
- Calendar integration with the gnome-panel calendar.
- Contact sharing with other software such as Pidgin
- Supports WebDAV and iCal web calendars
- Multiple account management
- GPG key and certificate storage
- Plugin support (including MAPI plugins for interfacing with Microsoft Exchange)

[image]

Comment: Especially the calendar integration for gmail is neat. I like evolution too. It has every feature I ever wished - except for [this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/46861/17789)

Answer (score 3):

I have just recently switched to Thunderbird so see how development has progressed.  At this point I am reasonably impressed.  The setup for POP/IMAP email accounts was the easiest with which I have ever had to deal.

With a simple extension I had communication with Unity.  Not shown in the image below is the indication of new mail in my various inboxes.

[image]

I have not had the opportunity to experiment any newsgroup reader functionailty.

Like Evolution, I like the fact that Thunderbird provides me access to my GMail contact list.  Additionally, I like the fact that Thunderbird works with tabs, one of which is my Google Calendar; not a reasonably close facsimile, but the actual Google Calendar webpage.

In the past I have enjoyed KMail, Evolution, Claws Mail, and Thunderbird.  Currently I am very much liking Thunderbird.  For a list of the features of Thunderbird 3.1, refer to: http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/features/#easy-upgrade

Comment: Wunk. Thanks for the suggestion ! , Thunderbird is great.But   how you can keep the program running in the messaging menu? . I've added the extension , but when I close thunderbird it closes also.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know of any method for keeping something up and running in the message indicator when Thunderbird is not running.